# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{cx}=\left(\frac{a-b}{c}\right)f'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Suppose that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $0$. For real numbers $a,b,c$ with $c\neq 0$, prove that 
>   $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{cx}=\left(\frac{a-b}{c}\right)f'(0).$$

---

As $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, we can get two limits where $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$:
     $$\lim\limits_{x_1\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_1)-f(0)}{x_1-0}=f'(0);\;\;\;\;\;\lim\limits_{x_2\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_2)-f(0)}{x_2-0}=f'(0)$$

To get $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{cx}=\frac{a-b}{c}f'(0)$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c\neq 0$. We do the followings:
     \begin{align*}
  \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{cx}&=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(ax)-f(0)+f(0)-f(bx)}{cx-0}\\
  &=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{f(ax)-f(0)}{c(x-0)}-\frac{f(bx)-f(0)}{c(x-0)}\right)\\
  &\text{Now let $x=x_1/a$ and $x=x_2/b$ respectly, then we have:}\\
  \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{cx}&=\lim\limits_{x_1,x_2\rightarrow 0}\left(a\frac{f(x_1)-f(0)}{c(x_1-0)}-b\frac{f(x_2)-f(0)}{c(x_2-0)}\right)\\
  &=\left(\frac{a-b}{c}\right)f'(0)
  \end{align*}

---

Can someone check this solution right or not? If not right, please give me a hit or suggestion to write a better one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to consider the cases $a=0$ and $b=0$ as your development tacitly assumed that $ab\ne 0$.

Comment: It looks good but in my opinion you should write "Let $x_1=ax$" instead of "Let $x={x_1\over a}$" and write the step using definition of $f'(0)$ (your first step) after declaring $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @Dr.MV When $a=0,b=0$, I would have $f(0)-f(0)/x-0$, I don't see how to receive the result

Comment: If both $a$ and $b$ are zero, the proof is trivial.  But you will need to show the cases for which one or the other, but not both, is zero.  You're almost there!!  Don't give up now.

Comment: @Dr.MV I will show those cases at the last second equal sign?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  Or even from the beginning as special cases.